# How to keep Twitter API session alive after logging through Facebook API?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, twitter, facebook-php-sdk

The two different API code for Facebook, Google+ and Twitter is located in three respective different folders: "facebook" folder for the Facebook API, "twitter" folder for Twitter and "google_plus".

I'm trying to allow people to log on through Twitter and access the application, and give them the option to also log on through Facebook after logging on through Twitter and keep the twitter-based data after they logged through Facebook. I would basically like them to be able to view both their Twitter and Facebook feeds and other data mixed together at the same time.

I tried to implement sessions, but it looks like if they log through Facebook after logging through Twitter first, the Twitter session variable content become NULL and only Facebook session data is displayed. How can I manipulate the sessions so that Twitter session data can be kept when a user log through Facebook as well?

Below is what I did to test the data:

```
session_start();
require('../database/connection.php');
require_once('../twitter/twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php');
require_once('../twitter/config.php');
include_once '../facebook/fbmain.php';
```

Here I'll test the $_SESSION variable to see if twitter data is kept after a user logs through Facebook as well .. but Twitter data become NULL instead and the $_SESSION array only show Facebook data .. How can I make Twitter session data STAY after someone logs through Facebook as well ?

```
var_dump($_SESSION); var_dump(session_id());  // twitter session data gets overriden by facebook data although the variable names are different ..
/* If access tokens are not available redirect to connect page. */

if (empty($_SESSION['facebook_id']) && (empty($_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token']) || empty($_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token_secret']))) {
header('Location: ./clearsessions.php');
}
else {
/* Get user access tokens out of the session. */
$access_token = $_SESSION['access_token'];


/* Create a TwitterOauth object with consumer/user tokens. */
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);

/* If method is set change API call made. Test is called by default. */
$content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');
$json = json_encode($content);
$data = json_decode($json,true);
$screen_name = $data["screen_name"];
$name = $data["name"];
$image_url = $data['profile_image_url'];
$_SESSION['screen_name'] = $screen_name;
$_SESSION['image_url'] = $image_url;
$query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username ='$screen_name'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$result_count = mysql_num_rows($result); 
if($result_count == 0) {
$insert = "INSERT INTO Users(username) VALUES('$screen_name')";
$result_insert = mysql_query($insert);
}

}

if(isset($_SESSION['oauth_token']) && isset($_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']) && isset($_SESSION['facebook_id'])){

$user = $_SESSION['facebook_id'];

}



?>
```

Comment: What happens here: `header('Location: ./clearsessions.php');`? Also, maybe twitter and facebook share session variable names, so one overwrites the other? Which is something you'd have to find out by looking at the libraries.

Comment: That's not the case ... the sessions have two different ids ...

Comment: I changed the variable names too ...

Comment: If the clearsessions.php is the one from twitteroauth, then your session gets destroyed if you have neither a facebook id and tokens. Not only does it get destroyed it also regenerates your session and thus you have a new session id. As soon as you have a new session id you have new session values ( empty at the start ).  Try refreshing to connect.php `header('Location: ./connect.php');` instead of clearsessions.php and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging his application it turned out his Facebook was setup to redirect to his `www` subdomain, while Twitter was setup to redirect to no subdomain. The session was lost since the cookie was issued on a strict basis.

So after logging in via Facebook the user was taken to `www` which issued one session/cookie, after logging via Twitter the user was taken to plain domain, where a completely different session/cookie was being issued/presented.

Solutions to the problem:

1. Wildcard cookie `session_set_cookie_params( 0, '/', '.mywebsite.com' );`
2. Better solution - don't mix and match subdomains, set one canonical URL and stick to it.

Comment: Thank you .. U ARE the man soulseekah .. posted this question so many times and no one answered . May you become the next Zuckerberg !!  ur answer is accepted !!!