# How can I rewrite this kind of URL with htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I rewrite this kind of url with htaccess .. the example is below with these dummy urls

update the .htaccess so when someone goes to http://cheapbats.mediagroup.com/19 it redirects them to http://cheapbats.cmediagroup.com/index.php?ref=19

`The rule is, if not a directory or file,` and it is a number, then redirect it to index.php?
ref=[number]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?ref=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Can you put more details what didn't work. Keep in mind this is a silent (Internal) rewrite so it won't change the URL in the browser.

Comment: Thank you ... can you recommend me where to learn htaccess usage ?

Comment: This is official doc: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html but mostly it will come by practice and SO answers

Comment: ....do you think you can help me with this question .. no one is answering it .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20052818/how-to-keep-twitter-api-php-session-alive-after-logging-through-facebook-api