# do Facebook API developers have the right to edit the base base_facebook.php class?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'd like to know if it's common for facebook developers to edit this class below in order to cutomize some stuff .. It looks like facebook api erases twitter api sessions and I want users.. can I modify it ?

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php

Comment: It's a class meant to be extended, notice the declaration of the class `abstract class BaseFacebook`. it wouldn't even work if you do not implement the abstract methods. You can then also just change other methods, as long as they're eitjer protected or public ( and not 'final' but that's getting in to deep maybe ;) )

Comment: Ofcourse you can you can even write your own facebook sdk

Comment: @JaapMoolenaar Thanks .. How come I can't see my $_SESSION data from the Twitter API session after I log in through the Facebook API .. I'd like the twitter data to remain in the session variable if I decide to login through facebook as well .. but twitter data gets lost ..How can I prevent this ? I have both the twitter api and facebook code on the same server ..any thoughts please ?

Comment: In general, you should never modify a library (unless you are making changes to submit to the core project, which Facebook may well permit on Github). But, as @Jaap says, libraries that offer classes can usually be extended.

Comment: @halfer How come I can't see my $_SESSION data from the Twitter API session after I log in through the Facebook API .. I'd like the twitter data to remain in the session variable if I decide to login through facebook as well .. but twitter data gets lost ..How can I prevent this ? I have both the twitter api and facebook code on the same server ..any thoughts please ?

Comment: @Stack: the question about Twitter should be asked as a new question (with the code you are using and what you have done to debug the problem, of course). Comments under a post are just for clarification, not general discussion `:-)`.

Comment: @halfer I posted but no one responded .. it looks like this site is not too active like it used to do ..

Comment: I'm with halfer on this. How about a link to the question? If your question isn't getting enough attention you can try placing a bounty on it ;-)

Comment: @JaapMoolenaar  Here is a link to the question ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20052818/how-to-keep-twitter-api-php-session-alive-after-logging-through-facebook-api I'd totally appreciate it if you could tell me why my twitter session gets erased .. I am using Abraham's oauth library for twitter  https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth and this one for facebook http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/php-sdk-3-0-graph-api-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/

Comment: @JaapMoolenaar  .. once someone logins in through twitter , everything shows from twitter , but then when he logins through facebook , the twitter $_SESSION variable data get erased and I only see facebook data ..